# PhantomJS not loading javascript (jasmine) library?

Tags: jasmine, phantomjs

I'm new to phantom and hoped there's something obvious I've missed.  I've stripped this sample to the minimum in order to show the problem with, in this case, integration with Jasmine.

In my javascript file I call `page.open(...)` and pass in as an argument the name of a local html file that includes Jasmine in it.  The html file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<h2>
    Reporter</h2>
<head>
    <title>Jasmine Spec Runner</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Content/jasmine.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/External/Jasmine/jasmine.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jasmine.getEnv();
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmine.TeamcityReporter());
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmine.TrivialReporter());
        jasmine.getEnv().execute();
    </script>
</head>
```

When I call `phamtomjs myJavaScriptFile.js myHtmlFile.htm` I get a message from phantom about how it can't find the variable named jasmine. (referring to the `jasmine.getEnv()` method call.)

I know for a fact the jasmine.js file is visible in that html file, so I'm not sure what phantom has a problem with, or how to debug the problem further?

Comment: Is the path Scripts/External/Jasmine/jasmine.js correct? If PhantomJS can't load it, quite possibly it can't resolve the location of the resources.

Comment: Does Phantom use an environment variable or other means to determine what path(s) to look at when finding resources?  My installation of Phantom is in `c:\phantom` (not very imaginative) but I'm calling it from the folder in which myHtmlFile.htm lives-- the Scripts/External/Jasmine subfolder lives beneath that.  (Thanks, before I forget, for PhantomJS-- much appreciated.)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a pathing problem on my part.  Phantom didn't like backslashes in the htm file path, but wanted forward ones.  When I did that finding jasmine was no longer a problem:

```
phantomjs c:\folder1\jasmine_tests\myJavaScriptFile.js c:\folder1/jasmine_tests/myHtmlFile.htm
```

Comment: Very peculiar. Please file an bug in our issue tracker! Thanks.